# Good rebuses come in nines

Tags: rebus

A teacher might do this if a student is making rebuses during class.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> CASTIGATE

Explanation:

> cast + gate

Comment: but where does the middle letter come from?

Comment: @Bass: From your ability to add,  =D  Rebuses don't have to literally contain every word of the expression or every letter of every word.  They can be Morse code, if you will.   Take a gander at these: fun-with-words.com/rebus_puzzles.html,  Many of them are missing components.