# Chew on this, Wordster!

Tags: rebus

A teacher might [this](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/70007/good-rebuses-come-in-nines) if a student does **this** during class:

[image: ![enter image description here] [image]

Comment: Are you saving this to be answered by Wordster or is it free for all? Because I wouldn't want to take it from him :)

Comment: It's a dog eat dog world, QT!

Comment: @QuantumTwinkie:  Thanx for being so cosiderate! :)  I only just discovered this.

Comment: @Chowzen:  LOL!  Good one.  I only just discovered this.  The irony?  I had one ready for eventual posting that was the doer of your word. ;)   In any case, I don't know who the woman is.

Comment: @Wordster A tip for you. If you [google search](https://www.google.com/imghp) the [picture's image address](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mXFg7.jpg) you can [find out](https://www.google.com/search?tbs=sbi:AMhZZivkALb1uncfWUi09i5LUiIE1UaZ4-wyBvbwBP26nNfjBzpcpUXzrY8d6o2taxqb8zAmGC1TULBwIilEIPhCc9ZKko62yf2i9lsYZ9BgZ3TClpmDnssoWelsNGSWQfbpWxqnbWhR0Wdyy-qhKVVOP9T6CAlM1-K0zhYnVyJkdpqt9zSxpqAYI4Gew6RwdLz2NEpEksD6pkAEnYVqyFK2wVNLR8Y9FEV54_1JLkP3SrQTHQxTRW0a50HX_1hLEUESvsVIa8dNCMDhHufoK2O8hwIrtZ_1g-9MqTZv5tIIgwhfOMaVpQ51Gj98H003J2IF59Hu3ikoQkB&hl=en).

Comment: @Chowzen:  I never knew about the image address.  Thank you for that. But isn't looking it up considered cheating?

Comment: Only if the question-poster specifies [tag:no-computers].  That's one of the valid tags

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think your word is

> MASTICATE (i.e., chew)

constructed as

> MAST + KATE (Duchess of Cambridge, formerly Middleton).

And of course

> the construction is decidedly reminiscent of that of CASTIGATE in the linked puzzle.